# XPath 3.0 tool for Windows that can search in all XML files in a directory

Tags: xml, xpath

Which tools can I use on Windows to search XML files using XPath 3.0 or above, specifying a root directory, rather than individual files?

Answer (score 0):

Saxon can do this. If you want it interactive, try the Gizmo tool. Example:

```
>SaxonEE12-2J % java -cp saxon-ee-12.2.jar net.sf.saxon.Gizmo
Saxon Gizmo 12.2
/>set $in = collection('file:/Users/mike/GitHub/xsdtests-results?on-error=ignore')
/>show count($in)
51
/>show distinct-values($in//*/node-name())
Found 21 items
out
testSuiteResults
testResult
...
/>show $in//testcase/@set/string(.)
Found 31 items
MS-Group2006-07-15
MS-Particles2006-07-15
MS-Particles2006-07-15
...
MS-Regex2006-07-15
/>show $in//testcase[@set="MS-Regex2006-07-15"]/comment
Found 5 items
<comment>Regex [ae-] is now invalid in XSD 1.1</comment>
...
/>quit
```